# What is the meaning of this output in the console when I run model.fit_generator in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new working with Keras. The code works correctly, but I would like to know the meaning of the values shown in the epochs. I am using the following code.

Where it says `46/46` and `226/277`, what is the meaning of these numbers? Why 2 appear when normally only appears for example `100/100`?

```
import sys
import os
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.python.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import  Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K

K.clear_session()


data_entrenamiento = '/content/DatosEntrenamiento' #images

"""
Parameters
"""
epocas=20
longitud, altura = 28, 28
batch_size = 32
pasos = 1000
validation_steps = 300
filtrosConv1 = 32
filtrosConv2 = 64
tamano_filtro1 = (3, 3)
tamano_filtro2 = (2, 2)
tamano_pool = (2, 2)
clases = 3
lr = 0.0004


##Preparamos nuestras imagenes

generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    )

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255,validation_split=0.2)

entrenamiento_generador = generator.flow_from_directory(
    data_entrenamiento,
    target_size=(altura, longitud),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training')

validacion_generador = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_entrenamiento,
    target_size=(altura, longitud),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation')

cnn = Sequential()
cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtrosConv1, tamano_filtro1, padding ="same", input_shape=(longitud, altura, 3), activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=tamano_pool))

cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtrosConv2, tamano_filtro2, padding ="same"))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=tamano_pool))

cnn.add(Flatten())
cnn.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))
cnn.add(Dense(clases, activation='softmax'))

cnn.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=lr),
            metrics=['accuracy'])

his = cnn.fit_generator(
    entrenamiento_generador,
    steps_per_epoch=pasos,
    epochs=epocas,
    validation_data=validacion_generador,
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
```

The output is :

```
Found 7230 images belonging to 3 classes.
Found 1446 images belonging to 3 classes.

Epoch 1/20

46/46 [=========] - 1s 21ms/step...

226/226 [======] - 8s 36ms/step...

Epoch 2/20

46/46 [=========] - 1s 21ms/step ...

226/226 [=======] - 8s 35ms/step ...
```

Comment: 46/46 and 226/226 show the batch which is currently being trained.

Comment: Can you show your `model.fit`?

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal Thanks! and where I can found why are 46 and 226? I guess that they are numberImages / batch_size

Comment: @HaBom Yes! added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> steps_per_epoch: Total number of steps (batches of samples) to yield from generator before declaring one epoch finished and starting the next epoch. It should typically be equal to the number of unique samples of your dataset divided by the batch size.

For training you have 7230 images, it means 226 batches of 32 images. It is also the `steps_per_epoch` which is normally calculated by `steps_per_epoch = train_generator.n/batch_size`. But here you declare `steps_per_epoch=pasos (=1000)` which is larger than available training batches so it will take 226.

> validation_steps: Total number of steps (batches of samples) to yield from validation_data generator before stopping at the end of every epoch. It should typically be equal to the number of samples of your validation dataset divided by the batch size. Optional for Sequence: if unspecified, will use the len(validation_data) as a number of steps.

Here again, you declare a `validation_steps=300` which is higher than available validation batches (1446/32=46 batches). If you dont use `validation_steps`, you'll only see the training `226/226 [======] - 8s 36ms/step...` every epoch.